# ArrayList - add "same" objects (same => equals, hashCode), Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, equals, hashcode

Ive got one question. What happens when I try to add the "same" object twice to an ArrayList. With "the same" I mean an object of an individual class, which is identified as the same with equals() and hashCode(). It has different values for most of the member variables and was created from maybe different threads, but for equals() and hashCode() its the "same".
Does the second object then replace the first object?

Also, what happens if two threads try to add those objects exactly at the same time to the ArrayList? Is this even possible? If yes, what happens?

Thank you! :-)

[EDIT] Thanks for all the answers! Should I use synchronizedList then rather then using  "synchronize(list){}"? --> I read the docs, even with synchronizedList, for iterating synchronize(list) shall be used

[EDIT2]
Can a synchronizedList be declared as a member variable? I tried, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 16):

No, `ArrayList` doesn't attempt to detect duplicates at all - you can have an `ArrayList` with the exact same reference appearing multiple times. If you want a collection to avoid duplicates, you need a `Set` implementation - and if you *also* want to preserve insertion order, you probably want [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Note, however, that without locking `ArrayList` should *not* be mutated from multiple threads in the first place - it's simply not meant to be a thread-safe collection in that way. Several threads can *read* from an `ArrayList` without synchronization, but not mutate it. From the docs:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list

If you want to mutate a collection from multiple threads without locking, I suggest you look at the collections in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html).

Answer (score 7):

> Does the second object then replace
>   the first object?

No, most developers do explicit checks

```
if(!list.contains(foo)){
    list.add(foo);
}
```

> Also, what happens if two threads try
>   to add those objects exactly at the
>   same time to the ArrayList? Is this
>   even possible? If yes, what happens?

Yes, this is possible. If multiple threads write to/read from the same `ArrayList`, then use the `synchronized` keyword whenever you access this list

```
public List<Foo> getFoos(){
    synchronized(list){
        return list;
    }
}

public void addFoo(Foo foo){
    synchronized(list){
        list.add(foo);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As someone pointed out, I suppose checking whether or not the `ArrayList` contains the object to be added is quite expensive. If you want to ensure that the object is only added once, I'd follow the recommendation made below of using a [LinkedHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). According to the API, when attempting to [add](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) to this data structure it

> Adds the specified element to this set
>   if it is not already present. More
>   formally, adds the specified element e
>   to this set if this set contains no
>   element e2 such that (e==null ?
>   e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set
>   already contains the element, the call
>   leaves the set unchanged and returns
>   false.

Comment: -1 Each call to `ArrayList.contains` is O(n). This is a terrible way to create a unique list. `LinkedHashSet` is better for that.

Comment: but when using LinkedHashSet accessing it must be synchronized too, correct? Then why not use a synchronizedList?

Comment: @nano7, of course it must be synchronized. just because you changed the collection doesn't mean you change the synchronization policy. you're free to use whatever synchronized data structure you want, but if you're going to use a `LinkedHashSet`, i'd recommend using a `synchronizedSet`.

Comment: Like this? Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new LinkedHashSet<objecttype>()); How do I declare a member variable of this type? is its type "LinkedHashSet<objecttype>()"? Do I create then the synchronizedSet manually and set it as the member variable (with casting it)? If a object is added once to the list, the same object cant be added again, so synchronizing "add" is unnecessary, isnt it?

Answer (score 4):

It will allow to add simply. List has nothing to do with `hashCode()`, `equals()` while insertion it doesn't care for duplicate.

`ArrayList` isn't thread safe so you might not get desired result. you can have `synchronizedList` from `Collections` class

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` can contain multiple references to the same exact object (identity equivalence).  It doesn't check `equals()` or `hashCode()` when adding objects.

You will just end up with two references in your ArrayList.

`ArrayList` is NOT thread-safe...so the behaviour if you try to have two threads add at the same time is undefined.  Maybe try using a [`SynchronizedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) if you want to do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to add the same object twice, it will work, or if you try to add 2 objects with everything the same, it will still work. It is not best practice to do that because its harder to maintain the list.

overall: you shouldn't do it