# ArrayList Object Value Change due to same HaschCode (Duplicate Objects)

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Im creating an array List of objects and adding those objects to it randomly:

```
public ArrayList makePerks(int roun, int ran) {
    perks.clear();
    int perkAm = Menu.randInt(6, 7);
    Perk last = new Perk();
    for (int i = 0; i < perkAm; ++i) {
        Perk tempPerk = new Perk();
        tempPerk = generate(ran, roun);
        System.out.println(tempPerk.name + " - " + tempPerk.cost);
        perks.add(tempPerk);
    }
    System.out.println("_________________________");
    return perks;
}
```

What this does, is it creates perks randomly using some other functions. The output from the Print statement in this is as follows:

```
12-11 01:51:07.331: I/System.out(3900): Gain Profit - 4
12-11 01:51:07.341: I/System.out(3900): Strength - 11
12-11 01:51:07.351: I/System.out(3900): Gain Profit - 5
12-11 01:51:07.361: I/System.out(3900): High Premium - 17
12-11 01:51:07.371: I/System.out(3900): Moderate Speed - 5
12-11 01:51:07.381: I/System.out(3900): Nomad - 11
12-11 01:51:07.381: I/System.out(3900): _________________________
```

Now inside one of my activities (android), i retrieve the array List that is returned from the function above:

```
tempItems = perkGen.makePerks(plrRound, plrRank);
```

And now i want to add the data to an ArrayList adapter using a for loop like so:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tempItems.size(); ++i) {
        shopItems.add(tempItems.get(i));
        System.out.println(tempItems.get(i).name + " - " + tempItems.get(i).cost);
        perk_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

It all works fine except the output is as follows:

```
12-11 01:51:07.381: I/System.out(3900): Gain Profit - 5
12-11 01:51:07.391: I/System.out(3900): Strength - 11
12-11 01:51:07.391: I/System.out(3900): Gain Profit - 5
12-11 01:51:07.391: I/System.out(3900): High Premium - 17
12-11 01:51:07.391: I/System.out(3900): Moderate Speed - 5
12-11 01:51:07.391: I/System.out(3900): Nomad - 11
```

If you havent noticed, where i have 2 duplicates; (Gain Profit) in the first output, they are 4 and 5, but in the second one they are 5 and 5. How is this possible? Does this have something to do with there being 2 similar objects in the array? Or is it something im doing wrong ?

Here are the same outputs with hashcodes:

```
12-11 02:25:31.281: I/System.out(4024): Moderate Speed - 8 - -1307644808
12-11 02:25:31.291: I/System.out(4024): Agility - 9 - -1307646728
12-11 02:25:31.301: I/System.out(4024): Agility - 5 - -1307647072
12-11 02:25:31.301: I/System.out(4024): Prolix - 13 - -1307638016
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): IDA - 5 - -1307641072
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): Moderate Speed - 11 - -1307644808
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): _________________________
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): Moderate Speed - 11 - -1307644808
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): Agility - 9 - -1307646728
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): Agility - 5 - -1307647072
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): Prolix - 13 - -1307638016
12-11 02:25:31.321: I/System.out(4024): IDA - 5 - -1307641072
12-11 02:25:31.331: I/System.out(4024): Moderate Speed - 11 - -1307644808
```

You may also notice that in the output above, the agility maintains the correct output, the moderate Speed however does not. This is because the hashcodes are the same for the agility items. How can this be avoided or changed?

Thanks you for your help :)

If i need to post more code just ask :) But i hope you have all the information you need :)
Thanks again :)

Another Addition to the code as requested THE GENERATE METHOD:

```
public Perk generate(int ran, int roun) {
    final DecimalFormat mb = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    int perkT = Menu.randInt(0, 4);
    Perk tempPerk = new Perk();

    if (perkT == 0) { // Speed
        ArrayList tempArray = new ArrayList();
        tempArray = getSpeedPerks(ran, roun);
        Perk tePerk = new Perk();
        tePerk = getPerk(tempArray);
        tempPerk = tePerk;
        int randBonus = Menu.randInt(0, 3);
        tempPerk.cost += randBonus;
        // Perk Increase Formula:
        double lvlBonus = roun * ran;
        double lvlInc = lvlBonus / 10;
        double bon = 1.0 + lvlInc;
        tempPerk.plusInc *= (bon);
        tempPerk.cost *= (bon);
        tempPerk.desc = ("Increases the effectiveness of each tap:\n"
                + "    - Tap Power + " + mb.format(tempPerk.plusInc));

    }
    if (perkT == 1) { // Minus
        ArrayList tempArray = new ArrayList();
        tempArray = getMinusPerks(ran, roun);
        Perk tePerk = new Perk();
        tePerk = getPerk(tempArray);
        tempPerk = tePerk;
        int randBonus = Menu.randInt(0, 3);
        tempPerk.cost += randBonus;
        // Perk Increase Formula:
        double lvlBonus = roun * ran;
        double lvlInc = lvlBonus / 10;
        double bon = 1.0 + lvlInc;
        tempPerk.minusDec *= (bon);
        tempPerk.cost *= (bon);
        tempPerk.desc = ("Decreases the bars speed:\n"
                + "   - Bar Speed - " + mb.format(tempPerk.minusDec));
    }
    if (perkT == 2) { // Auto
        ArrayList tempArray = new ArrayList();
        tempArray = getAutoPerks(ran, roun);
        Perk tePerk = new Perk();
        tePerk = getPerk(tempArray);
        tempPerk = tePerk;
        int randBonus = Menu.randInt(0, 3);
        tempPerk.cost += randBonus;
        // Perk Increase Formula:
        if (roun > 0 & roun <= 5) {
            int rand = Menu.randInt(0, 1);
            if (rand == 0) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 30;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            } else {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 60;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 2;
            }
        } else if (roun > 5 & roun <= 10) {
            int rand = Menu.randInt(0, 1);
            if (rand == 0) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 20;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            } else {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 60;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 3;
            }
        } else if (roun > 10 & roun <= 15) {
            int rand = Menu.randInt(0, 1);
            if (rand == 0) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 15;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            } else {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 20;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 2;
            }
        } else if (roun > 15 & roun <= 20) {
            int rand = Menu.randInt(0, 1);
            if (rand == 0) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 10;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            } else {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 20;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 2;
            }
        } else if (roun > 20 & roun <= 24) {
            int rand = Menu.randInt(0, 1);
            if (rand == 0) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 5;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            } else {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 10;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 2;
            }
        } else if (roun == 25) {
            int rand = Menu.randInt(0, 1);
            if (rand == 0) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 5;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 2;
            } else {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 3;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            }
        } else if (ran == 2) {
            int rand = Menu.randInt(0, 2);
            if (rand == 0) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 5;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 2;
            }
            if (rand == 1) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 3;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            }
            if (rand == 2) {
                tempPerk.autoClick = 2;
                tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
            }
        } else if (ran == 3) {
            tempPerk.autoClick = 1;
            tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
        } else {
            tempPerk.autoClick = 1;
            tempPerk.clickAmount = 1;
        }
        tempPerk.desc = ("Auto Taps at a fixed rate:\n" + "   - Taps + "
                + mb.format(tempPerk.clickAmount) + "\n   - every "
                + tempPerk.autoClick + " seconds");
    }
    if (perkT == 3) { // Reward
        ArrayList tempArray = new ArrayList();
        tempArray = getRewardPerks(ran, roun);
        Perk tePerk = new Perk();
        tePerk = getPerk(tempArray);
        tempPerk = tePerk;
        int randBonus = Menu.randInt(0, 3);
        tempPerk.cost += randBonus;
        // Perk Increase Formula:
        double lvlBonus = roun * ran;
        double lvlInc = lvlBonus / 10;
        double bon = 1.0 + lvlInc;
        tempPerk.cost *= (bon);
        tempPerk.rewardBonus += lvlInc / 5;
        tempPerk.desc = ("Increases amount of tokens gathered at the end of each round:\n"
                + "   - Tokens + " + tempPerk.rewardBonus);
    }
    if (perkT == 4) { // All Rounder
        ArrayList tempArray = new ArrayList();
        tempArray = getAllRounPerks(ran, roun);
        Perk tePerk = new Perk();
        tePerk = getPerk(tempArray);
        tempPerk = tePerk;
        int randBonus = Menu.randInt(0, 3);
        tempPerk.cost += randBonus;
        // Perk Increase Formula:
        double lvlBonus = roun * ran;
        double lvlInc = lvlBonus / 10;
        double bon = 1.0 + lvlInc;
        tempPerk.plusInc *= (bon);
        tempPerk.minusDec *= (bon);
        tempPerk.cost *= (bon);
        tempPerk.desc = ("Increases the effectiveness of several stats:\n"
                + "   - Tap Power + " + mb.format(tempPerk.plusInc)
                + "\n   - Bar Speed - " + mb.format(tempPerk.minusDec)
                + "\n   - Tokens + " + tempPerk.rewardBonus);
    }
    return tempPerk;
}
```

This line here:

```
tePerk = getPerk(tempArray);
```

Makes the tePerk equal to a perk from a list, this may be causing the problem.

Thank you again :)

Comment: Hi why you have used the code ` Perk last = new Perk(); ` and are you going to access perks instance variable anywhere?

Comment: `Perk tempPerk = new Perk();`
This line is useless since you are changing tempPerk with this line 
`tempPerk = generate(ran, roun);`

Comment: Hey. Im not using last at the moment it is unrelated to the current code. But i will use it later. And yes tempPerk is generated in the generate() function as you can see: tempPerk = generate()

Comment: also you should use .addAll() method instead of .add() like "shopItems.addAll(tempItems);", means no need to loop through it...:)

Comment: despite all that its giving me the right value the first time i print it out so it shouldnt be anything to do with how im generating it right?

Comment: so when i say addAll how do i determine how many i want to add?

Comment: can you see printing the `tempItems.get(i).hashcode()` as well

Comment: Yes, i posted them below it seems that sometimes they are the same. What would i do in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i fixed the issue. The issue was that i was retrieving the objects from another arraylist. So imagine you have an ArrayList called A. And another called B. So imagine you are retrieving Objects from ArrayList A and Moving them across into B. If i retrieve the same object from A twice and moving it into B, inside B the two objects will have the same hashCode which will cause problems.

So to fix that, i made a new bridging object that inherits all of the values from objects coming out of a and then passing the new object into B instead of directly moving A's objects. I did this like so:

```
public Perk getPerk(ArrayList<Perk> perks) {
    Perk tempPerk = new Perk();
    Perk newMPerk = new Perk();
    ArrayList<Perk> tempPerks = new ArrayList();
    tempPerks.clear();
    int random = Menu.randInt(1, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < perks.size(); ++i) {
        if (hasRar(perks.get(i), random)) {
            tempPerks.add(perks.get(i));
        }
    }
    if (tempPerks.isEmpty() == false) {
        int nextRandom = Menu.randInt(0, tempPerks.size() - 1);
        tempPerk = tempPerks.get(nextRandom);
        newMPerk.name = tempPerk.name;
        newMPerk.cost = tempPerk.cost;
        newMPerk.rarity = tempPerk.rarity;
        newMPerk.minusDec = tempPerk.minusDec;
        newMPerk.plusInc = tempPerk.plusInc;
        newMPerk.rewardBonus = tempPerk.rewardBonus;

    } else {
        Perk newPerk = new Perk();
        newPerk.name = "Extra";
        newPerk.cost = 0;
        newPerk.rarity = 1;
        newPerk.minusDec = 0;
        newPerk.plusInc = 0;
        newPerk.rewardBonus = 0;
        newMPerk = newPerk;
    }
    return newMPerk;
}
```

So NewMPerk inherits all of teh variables: Name cost etc. From the Object that is retrieved from Array List A. And then it is returned and added into Array List B. Since NewMPerk is a new Object of the type Perk, it will have a different hashCode everytime.

Hope this can help other people :)

If you have any questions feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code for generate method. 
 I am not sure but from wht ever code you have provided, It looks like in generate method you are reusing the object for example: 1st time  perk returned with name "Moderate Speed" and cost 8 and you add it to list and even print it. Then again same object is used for "Moderate Speed" with value 11 and you add it to list and print it...Now list have 2 same objects of perks.

Since 1st time you are adding and printing one perk at a time you are seeing 2 different value. And 2nd time your printing all the values in a for loop and hence you are seeing same values.

Comment: Ill post the generate method. BUt it is weird how the same thing did not happen for the second example with agility and moderate speed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that some objects are sharing the same hashCode. It is confusing that some entries share the same hashcode when others do not. I had a look at these links, but they werent very helpful, but its an issue with the hashcode:

http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/collections/ListHashCode.html

and

[ArrayList - add "same" objects (same => equals, hashCode), Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138315/arraylist-add-same-objects-same-equals-hashcode-threads)

Thank You Sateesh Cheveri

This line:

```
tePerk = getPerk(tempArray);
```

Makes the teTerk object equal to a perk from a list. Which may be causing it to have the same hashCode if two perks are getting the same item from that list. Not sure how to fix it though.

This isnt the answer, but i know what the issue is now.

Answer (score 0):

1) There are some details missing in the question. However, I assume shopItems is a HashSet, and you are trying to copy all items from an ArrayList into it.

When copying between collections, keep in mind that while array lists accept duplicates, sets don't. Duplicates are determined by the equals() method, so assuming x.equals(y), trying to add x to a set that contains y will fail.

Make your Perk.equals() reflect the true identity of your instances, so that "duplicates" occur only when you expect them to occur (and then adapt hashcode() accordingly).

2) your makePerks() method seems to use a data member, instead of creating a new list. This can cause trouble, because the returned list may change unexpectedly at some point after the invocation. This may explain the change you see.